Что значат эти скобки <> в Java?
Я понимаю что <> это указывает на некоторую типизацию обьекта. Как к примеру ArrayList<String>  значит можем заносить только обьекты типа String. Для чего это нужно? Можно ли эту конструкцию назвать дженериками?

Это связано с дженериками, но дженерик - это не сама эта конструкция, а тип ArrayList в данном случае.

возможно есть сайт где можно подробно изучать данную тему? И хотелось бы понять в каких случаях его использовать и вообще его точное название. Но интернет толкает что это "дженерики". Но по всей видимости немного ошибочное мнение так как дженерики это типизированый класс Class , к примеру. Если я ошибаюсь - поправьте

@AlinaKlishyna Ну а тут типизированный ArrayList. Почему дженерики должны быть именно с классами связаны? Впрочем, чем ArrayList не класс.
